# How to modify the query so that it performs well

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Below is the query which I want to modify, there are over 30k+ execution on daily basis and we dont know how this can be modify, can somebody help me to solve this.

```
insert into #ALERT_AND_BUSINESSES_IDS
    select 
        AlertID,
        BusinessID = c.value('.','bigint')
    from Alerts
    cross apply
        XMLBusinessIDs.nodes('/root/id') as m(c)
    where Active = 1
```

Comment: You're truly stuck if you can't get rid of that XQuery. Also, how select is the WHERE clause? Is Active=1 a very small set that is indexed and allows for a lot of row eliminations before you have to get the XML? If not, make it so and make sure that index is covering.

Comment: There could be so many reasons for this to not perform, like bad indexes. However, chances are it's because of the fact you're using XML. How volatile is the data in `XMLBusinessIDs`? Because if it is not, why not store it in a table? You can update that table whenever it changes, but it'll help your query a lot.